# Как использовать библиотеку NET Framework 4.5 из приложения на 3.5?

Tags: .net, com, appdomain

Есть приложение написанное под 3.5. Надо подменить одну из его библиотек на новую, написанную под 4.5. Исходники библиотеки есть. Исходников приложения нет.

Какие есть способы? Простейший - сделать библиотеку, поднимающую сервис на 4.5 и общающуюся с ним. Возможно, есть иные варианты? Взаимодействие через COM? Или путем загрузки библиотеки на 4.5 в ином домене?

Comment: А что именно вы используете из 4.5? Много ли такого кода в исходниках библиотеки? Самый простой путь - это в Target Framework указать платформу .NET 3.5 и скомпилировать библиотеку (если скомпилится, конечно) под 3.5.

Comment: А если выполнять программу под .NET 4.5?

Comment: Под 3.5 перекомпилировать не выйдет. Там используются сторонние библиотеки без исходников под 4.5. А что конкретно имеется ввиду под "выполнять программу под 4.5" ?